# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

the problem is with attribute c that is shown and says  dataframe has not it,it may be a little problem
but i do not know how to fix
I  posted the related code here,the class , it's usage and it's error

Main class

```
class DNNTrader(tpqoa.tpqoa):
    def __init__(self, conf_file, instrument, bar_length, window, lags, model, mu, std, units):
        super().__init__(conf_file)
        self.instrument = instrument
        self.bar_length = pd.to_timedelta(bar_length)
        self.tick_data = pd.DataFrame()
        self.raw_data = None
        self.data = None 
        self.last_bar = None
        self.units = units
        self.position = 0
        self.profits = []
        
        #*****************add strategy-specific attributes here******************
        self.window = window
        self.lags = lags
        self.model = model
        self.mu = mu
        self.std = std
        #************************************************************************
    
    def get_most_recent(self, days = 5):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            now = datetime.utcnow()
            now = now - timedelta(microseconds = now.microsecond)
            past = now - timedelta(days = days)
            df = self.get_history(instrument = self.instrument, start = past, end = now,
                                   granularity = "S5", price = "A").c.dropna().to_frame()
            df.rename(columns = {"c":self.instrument}, inplace = True)
            df = df.resample(self.bar_length, label = "right").last().dropna().iloc[:-1]
            self.raw_data = df.copy()
            self.last_bar = self.raw_data.index[-1]
            if pd.to_datetime(datetime.utcnow()).tz_localize("UTC") - self.last_bar < self.bar_length:
                self.start_time = pd.to_datetime(datetime.utcnow()).tz_localize("UTC") # NEW -> Start Time of Trading Session
                break
                
    def on_success(self, time, bid, ask):
        print(self.ticks, end = " ", flush = True)
        
        recent_tick = pd.to_datetime(time)
        df = pd.DataFrame({self.instrument:(ask + bid)/2}, 
                          index = [recent_tick])
        self.tick_data = self.tick_data.append(df)
        
        if recent_tick - self.last_bar > self.bar_length:
            self.resample_and_join()
            self.define_strategy()
            self.execute_trades()
    
    def resample_and_join(self):
        self.raw_data = self.raw_data.append(self.tick_data.resample(self.bar_length, 
                                                                  label="right").last().ffill().iloc[:-1])
        self.tick_data = self.tick_data.iloc[-1:]
        self.last_bar = self.raw_data.index[-1]
    
    def define_strategy(self): # "strategy-specific"
        df = self.raw_data.copy()
        
        #******************** define your strategy here ************************
        #create features
        df = df.append(self.tick_data) # append latest tick (== open price of current bar)
        df["returns"] = np.log(df[self.instrument] / df[self.instrument].shift())
        df["dir"] = np.where(df["returns"] > 0, 1, 0)
        df["sma"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.window).mean() - df[self.instrument].rolling(150).mean()
        df["boll"] = (df[self.instrument] - df[self.instrument].rolling(self.window).mean()) / df[self.instrument].rolling(self.window).std()
        df["min"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.window).min() / df[self.instrument] - 1
        df["max"] = df[self.instrument].rolling(self.window).max() / df[self.instrument] - 1
        df["mom"] = df["returns"].rolling(3).mean()
        df["vol"] = df["returns"].rolling(self.window).std()
        df.dropna(inplace = True)
        
        # create lags
        self.cols = []
        features = ["dir", "sma", "boll", "min", "max", "mom", "vol"]

        for f in features:
            for lag in range(1, self.lags + 1):
                col = "{}_lag_{}".format(f, lag)
                df[col] = df[f].shift(lag)
                self.cols.append(col)
        df.dropna(inplace = True)
        
        # standardization
        df_s = (df - self.mu) / self.std
        # predict
        df["proba"] = self.model.predict(df_s[self.cols])
        
        #determine positions
        df = df.loc[self.start_time:].copy() # starting with first live_stream bar (removing historical bars)
        df["position"] = np.where(df.proba < 0.47, -1, np.nan)
        df["position"] = np.where(df.proba > 0.53, 1, df.position)
        df["position"] = df.position.ffill().fillna(0) # start with neutral position if no strong signal
        #***********************************************************************
        
        self.data = df.copy()
    
    def execute_trades(self):
        if self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == 1:
            if self.position == 0:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING LONG")
            elif self.position == -1:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units * 2, suppress = True, ret = True) 
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING LONG")
            self.position = 1
        elif self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == -1: 
            if self.position == 0:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING SHORT")
            elif self.position == 1:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units * 2, suppress = True, ret = True)
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING SHORT")
            self.position = -1
        elif self.data["position"].iloc[-1] == 0: 
            if self.position == -1:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, self.units, suppress = True, ret = True) 
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
            elif self.position == 1:
                order = self.create_order(self.instrument, -self.units, suppress = True, ret = True)
                self.report_trade(order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
            self.position = 0
    
    def report_trade(self, order, going):
        time = order["time"]
        units = order["units"]
        price = order["price"]
        pl = float(order["pl"])
        self.profits.append(pl)
        cumpl = sum(self.profits)
        print("\n" + 100* "-")
        print("{} | {}".format(time, going))
        print("{} | units = {} | price = {} | P&L = {} | Cum P&L = {}".format(time, units, price, pl, cumpl))
        print(100 * "-" + "\n")
```

calling class

```
trader = DNNTrader("oanda.cfg", "EUR_USD", bar_length = "20min",
                   window = 50, lags = 5, model = model, mu = mu, std = std, units = 100000)
```

```
trader.get_most_recent()
trader.stream_data(trader.instrument, stop = 1000)
if trader.position != 0:
    close_order = trader.create_order(trader.instrument, units = -trader.position * trader.units,
                                      suppress = True, ret = True) 
    trader.report_trade(close_order, "GOING NEUTRAL")
    trader.position = 0
```

the error I face:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 trader.get_most_recent()
      2 trader.stream_data(trader.instrument, stop = 1000)
      3 if trader.position != 0:

Cell In[28], line 28, in DNNTrader.get_most_recent(self, days)
     26 now = now - timedelta(microseconds = now.microsecond)
     27 past = now - timedelta(days = days)
---> 28 df = self.get_history(instrument = self.instrument, start = past, end = now,
     29                        granularity = "S5", price = "A").c.dropna().to_frame()
     30 df.rename(columns = {"c":self.instrument}, inplace = True)
     31 df = df.resample(self.bar_length, label = "right").last().dropna().iloc[:-1]

File C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5902, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5895 if (
   5896     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5897     and name not in self._metadata
   5898     and name not in self._accessors
   5899     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5900 ):
   5901     return self[name]
-> 5902 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'
```

I try to create an object of the class and run it and the object must downloads historical data
but it gives an error on c attribute and says it  dose not have such one, I also use c as a  list but again it gives error

Comment: According to your traceback the dataframe (presumably) produced by method `get_history` does not have any column called `c`. The tpqoa get_history should always return a df with column c (closing). Can you
1. Print the intermediate df (or it's structure) returned by get_history to make sure it has a column 'c'?
2. Confirm which version of tpqoa you are using here